# MYSQL can I change how to LIMIT results dynamicly?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, limit

Instead of hardcoding query: LIMIT 3, i would like to get LIMIT number different every time i press the button.

That's what I've got so far:

```
$region=$_GET["region"];

$number=$_GET["limit"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('test') or die(mysql_error());

$sql1="SELECT size,price,member FROM buy  WHERE region= '".$region."' LIMIT = '".$number."'  ORDER BY price DESC "
```

Error I get is:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource

So LIMIT is empty

So I got two buttons: one set $number=3 another set $number=10 but I don't know how to put it inside SQL.

So far only option `WHERE region= '".$region."'` works.

Any ideas ?

Comment: This code example, along with the suggestions below, are open to SQL injection, unless PHP has some special treatment of the $_GET variable. One fix would be to use (string)(int)$number. The variable $region would also need to be checked. addslashes($region) is one way, I think - not very good at PHP.

Comment: (string)(int)$number? how about (int)$number what is the point of string as well?

Comment: You are right, I was thinking it needed to be a string to be able to be combined with other strings with the . operator.

Answer (score 3):

First - remove quotes around limit number.

Second, remove `=` before number.

Third - move LIMIT after ORDER BY

i think thats all :)

```
$sql1="SELECT size,price,member FROM buy  WHERE region= '".$region."' ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT ".(int) $number
```

Comment: Adn don't forget about escaping your `$region` :)

Answer (score 1):

A few points here:

- The MySQL LIMIT statement can take both a LIMIT and an OFFSET, this is the basics required for paging.  See [MySQL SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)
- Are you sure that the limit variable is being set on the URL?  You are using $_GET['limit'], but if it is not on the URL it will not have a value and it will break your query.  Try displaying/logging the SQL statement to see what is happenning.
- Ideally you should also sanitise all the $_GET variables and ensure they are valid